# Delete button is not working inside of bootstrap modal in Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I created pagination in Laravel, and I also created delete button that allows me to delete records which are works great. My next step is to upgrade the delete button with bootstrap modal. The bootstrap modal alone works fine without putting any code inside of the modal body.  After I copied the pasted delete code inside of the modal body, I’m getting errors it said:

```
Route [/admin/resellers/{{ $reseller->id ] not defined. (View:
```

But what I do not understand is that this routeing code works fine in Laravel code and is not working in bootstrap modal code when both are same codes! why! I have spent one hour trying to figure out, Any idea!

Before adding into the bootstrap code this works if works fine Laravel (without bootstrap modal).

```
<td class="center">
 <form action="/admin/resellers/{{ $reseller->id }}" method="POST">
     <strong><a href="/admin/resellers/{{ $reseller->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-mini" >
     <i class="fas fa-pen fa-fw"></i>View</a></strong>
          @method('DELETE')
          @csrf
     <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-mini"><i class="far fa-edit fa-fw"></i>Edit
     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-mini" ><i class="fas fa-times fa-fw"></i>Delete</button>
</form>
```

Button trigger modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletes">
    <i class="fas fa-times fa-fw"></i>Delete</button>
```

In router

```
Route::delete('/admin/resellers/{reseller}','ResellerController@destory');
```

Inside of bootstrap modal same delete coded

```
<!-- Delete Modal -->
<div class="modal modal-danger fade" id="deletes" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLabel"><h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form action="{{ route('/admin/resellers/{{ $reseller->id ') }}" method="POST">

            @method('DELETE')
            @csrf

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you, want to delete?</p>
            <input type="hidden" name="reseller-id" id="reseller-id" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times fa-fw"></i>No, Cancel it.</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-check fa-fw"></i>Yes, Delete it.</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or does this code is correct in javascript

```
$('#deletes').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
      
      var reseller-id = button.data('resellerid')
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-body #reseller-id').val(reseller-id);
})
```

Many times thanks for getting into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On blade `route()` method will work,  if you have name route. But you did not define any name route, so it would be :

```
<form action="{{ url('/admin/resellers/' . $reseller->id) }}" method="POST">
```

If you want to use name route, then define the route name as :

```
Route::delete('/admin/resellers/{reseller}','ResellerController@destory')->name('destoryReseller');
```

Then you can use like that :

```
<form action="{{ route('destoryReseller',  $reseller->id) }}" method="POST">
```